# Форматирование текста в Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, строки

Имею вот такое меню:

```
   <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/"><span class="activ">пункт1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/"><span>пункт2</span></a></li>
   </ul>
```

Необходимо воспользоваться [[@Html](/users/14007/htmlplus)](/users/14007/htmlplus).ActionLink, могу так написать

```
 <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/"><span class="@ViewBag.ClassActive">пункт1</span></a></li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Пункт1", ....)</li>
   </ul>
```

как мне строку "Пункт1" обернуть в <span class="@ViewBag.ClassActive">пункт1</span>?

а то выводиться как обычный текст. Хотел использовать Html.Raw и new HtmlString, но тип не подходит

> преобразование типа из
> "System.Web.IHtmlString" в "string"
> невозможно

Comment: Можно и на саму ссылку класс повесить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо [@Html](/users/14007/htmlplus).ActionLink, который формирует разметку типа `<a href="/....">пункт2</a>`, есть метод @Url.Action, который формирует только ссылку. Т.е. Вашу задачу можно решить так:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Пункт1", ....)"><span>пункт2</span></a></li>
```